# how to make a mediaplayer lists and randomize them in C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-media-player

i am very new to C# and i would like to randomize some songs after each other but don´t know how to make lists or randomize them i can only get one song to play (my songs are placed in a folder wich you can see after "sound location")

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = @"C:\stuff\stuff.wav";
player.Load();
player.Play();
```

Comment: May be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303138/c-sharp-playing-random-sound-files-from-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a

> List

to store all your paths:

```
List<string> listPath = new List<string>();
//...
listPath.Add(your path);
```

and use this to get a radom element::

```
string radomPath = listPath.OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
```